# why JAXBContext just get base object class A extends B ,just get A

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, classcastexception

`com.e1.ewx.base.model.weixinapi.Event` extends `com.e1.ewx.base.model.weixinapi.BaseMsg`

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Event.class);  
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Event eee = (Event)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlStr));  
System.out.println(eee.getMsgType());
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.e1.ewx.base.model.weixinapi.BaseMsg cannot be cast to com.e1.ewx.base.model.weixinapi.Event
    at Test.main(Test.java:49)
```

Why?

Comment: It seems, that result of function `unmarshal` can not be casted to type `Event`.

Comment: It seems your XML document does not contain an Event but just a BaseMsg. Please show us the root element in the xmlStr and the relevant XSD part/ JAXB classes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that xmlStr is the representation of a BaseMsg instance and not a Event instance.